# Django-- Case insensitive username

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

Before anybody marks it as duplicate, I know there are tons of similar or exactly same question, but none of the solution seemed to work for me and I am clueless.

As usual I want my User model from django.contrib.auth.models to have case insensitive username. I have tried both methods described [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/06/how-to-implement-case-insensitive-username.html). Unfortunately none of those worked for me. Do I also need to edit my views.py after going through one the method described in the link? what should I do to achieve case insensitiveness?

Here is my view

```
def login_page(request):
if(request.method == 'POST'):
    name = request.POST['user']
    if not User.objects.filter(username=name).exists():
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_user': 'user does not exist'})
    pwd = request.POST['pwd']
    user = authenticate(username=name, password=pwd)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_pwd': name})

else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Here is part of my models.py:

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = 
     '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
     return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()


class ContentItem(models.Model):
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='no title')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='no description')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image_board/posts/', 
    default='null')
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_likes(self):
        no = self.like_set.all().count()
        if no is not None:
        return no
    else:
        return 0


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
    related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #email = models.EmailField()
    #first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    #last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    personal_info = models.TextField(blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    expertise = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{5,15}$', message="Phone 
  number must be entered in the format: '+123456'. Between 5 and 15 digits 
  allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=16, 
blank=True)
contact_skype = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
contact_facebook = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
contact_linkedin = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
user_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='../media/img', 
default='../media/img/anon.png')

def __str__(self):
    return self.job_title

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

EDIT: For option 1 from the link I get following error while making migration:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-1.11-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 194, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 
'core.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

Option 2 throws no error but if i create a user with username "User" and try to login with username "user", it gives "user doesn't exist" error.

Comment: What is your app name?

Comment: image_board, Why does this matter? my backends.py is in project folder and not inside app folder. Does it make any difference?

Comment: But, is your `CustomUser` model in `image_board` app?

Comment: did you try `User.objects.filter(username__iexact=name).exists()`

Comment: Yes it is actually.

Comment: Yes, then change `'core.CustomUser'` to `'image_board.CustomUser'`

Comment: please see my comment on your answer. It now throws another error

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
def login_page(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        name = request.POST['user']
        temp_user = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=name)
        if not temp_user.exists():
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_user': 'user does not exist'})
        pwd = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=temp_user.username, password=pwd)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_pwd': name})

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py`, the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` should be a string which contains like this, `'<your_app_name>.CustomUser'`.

Have you checked that is `'core'`, the name of your app.?

**EDIT**:

Maybe try changing in your `Profile` model,

```
from django.conf import settings

user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Ok, I corrected that. Now I get following error.

image_board.Profile.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

Comment: And did you try following that hint?

Comment: The error could be in your `Profile` model, which has a link to `django.contrib.auth.User`. Change the link to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. If you post your models, it'd much easier.

Comment: Edited the answer, haven't tried it. But do give it a try!

Comment: Sorry if I am missing very basic thing, but now I get 

"The field image_board.Profile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'image_board.customuser', but app 'image_board' doesn't provide model 'customuser'.
"

Comment: @FazilZaid I should change every relation linking User to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, right? I have done that.

Comment: It's, `'image_board.CustomUser'` not `'image_board.customuser'`. Python is case-sensitive in that. change it

Comment: @FazilZaid, I have it as 'image_board.CustomUser'.

Comment: And did you change all ForeignKey to `User` to the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`??

Comment: I can "makemigrations" but not "migrate", migrate gives the above mentioned error

Comment: Also, did you change your backend settings to, `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('your_project_name.image_board.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend', )` ... And your backend should be in app folder.!!

Comment: No it doesn't work. Using backend throws no error but trying to login with same  username with different case throws "User doesn't exist"

Comment: That problem lies in your `backends.py` buddy. You may need to override your login method in your `backends.py` for that. Is your `authenticate()` function in your `backends.py` exactly like in the blog?

Comment: It's exactly same as in blog